# Android: How to embed one viewflipper as a child into another Viewflipper

Tags: android, database

I'm creating childview for viewflipper at runtime based on the no of records in database,
inflating a view and adding to viewflipper. While Clicking each childview of viewflipper, should have newviewflipper with some childs. How to achieve this?

**ViewFlipper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

**CustomViewSample.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
<com.sample.MjpegView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_video"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Java Code**

```
ViewFlipper viewflipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);

- **livevideocount** is an integer contains no of records from table.

for(int i=0;i<livevideocount;i++)
{
  MjpegView mv = (MjpegView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.CustomViewSample,null);
  mv.setVisibility(MjpegView.VISIBLE);
  viewflipper.addView(mv);
}
```

Clicking this MjpegView object should generate another viewflipper with 3 childviews.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not directly inflate dynamic content into ViewFliper.

You should add **dyna_layout** as `<LinearLayout />` or  `<RelativeLayout />` into your `ViewFlipper.xml`, consider `dyna_layout` as a ViewGroup:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)(viewflipper.findViewById(R.id.dyna_view));

MjpegView mv = (MjpegView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.CustomViewSample, parent);
mv.setVisibility(MjpegView.VISIBLE); //may use or not
parent.addView(mv);
```